WebAPI project upgrade from .NET 6.0 to .NET 8.0 throws error "Multiple constructors accepting all given argument found in type AspNetCoreApi.Startup"
I have to upgrade an ASP.NET Core Web API from .NET 6.0 to .NET 8.0. From Visual Studio installed, I installed .NET SDK 8.0.0 (X64) on my local machine. I installed upgrade assistant and upgraded to .NET 8.0.
My .csproj file shows TargetFramework 8.0 now.
Below is my code
public class Program
 {
     public static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();        
     }

     public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
             .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
             {
                 webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();                 
             });
 }

In Program.cs at CreateHostBuilder(args), I get an error
System.InvalidOperationException
  System.InvalidOperationException
  HResult=0x80131509
  Message=Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'AspNetCoreApi.Startup'. There should only be one applicable constructor.
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.TryFindMatchingConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ConstructorInfo& matchingConstructor, Nullable`1[]& parameterMap)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.FindApplicableConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ConstructorInfo& matchingConstructor, Nullable`1[]& matchingParameterMap)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services, Object instance)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.InitializeServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at AspNetCoreApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\CDHS\cdhs-kronos-dim-api\src\AspNetCoreApi\Program.cs:line 10
 There should only be one applicable constructor.
  Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.TryFindMatchingConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ConstructorInfo& matchingConstructor, Nullable`1[]& parameterMap)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.FindApplicableConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ConstructorInfo& matchingConstructor, Nullable`1[]& matchingParameterMap)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services, Object instance)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.InitializeServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at AspNetCoreApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\xxxxx\AspNetCoreApi\Program.cs:line 10

Below is my Startup.cs file. I also upgraded the Nuget packages. No compile time error but I am getting this error in Program.cs file at run time.
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public Startup(IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
           .Build();
    }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddRazorPages();
         services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

         services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
         //services.AddScoped<IXmlRepository, XmlRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IKronosCppsRepository, KronosCppsRepository>();
         services.AddScoped<IHrisRepository, HrisRepository>();
         services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
         services.AddScoped<IHrisIdentityRepository, HrisIdentityRepository>();
         services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
         services.AddScoped<IFileHelpers, FileHelpers>();
         services.AddTransient<ViewModels.PingIdTester.RadiusClient>();

         KronosCppsDbContext.ConnectionString = Configuration["Data:AspNetCoreApi:ConnectionStrings:KronosCppsConnectionString"];
         services.AddDbContext<KronosCppsDbContext>();
         var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(new KronosCppsMappingProfile());
            cfg.AddProfile(new HRISMappingProfile());
        });

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

        services.AddSingleton(mapper);
        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        .AddCookie(options =>)
               {
                    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F";
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F";                   
                    options.Events.OnRedirectToLogout = cxt => System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                })
         .AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
         {
             options.Audience = "Other";
             options.Authority = "";
             options.ForwardAuthenticate = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
             options.ClaimsIssuer = "Self";
             options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
             options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
             {
                 ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                 IssuerSigningKey = key
             };
             options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents()
             {
                 OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
                 {
                     c.NoResult();

                     //c.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                     c.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

                     return c.Response.WriteAsync("Forbidden");
                 },
                 OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
                 {
                     ctx.Success();
                     return System.Threading.Tasks.Task.CompletedTask;
                 }
             };
         })
         ;
            services.AddAuthorization(auth =>
        {
            auth.AddPolicy("Cookie, Bearer", new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build());
        });

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
            options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNetCore.Cookies";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
            options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        });

        services.AddMvc();
    }

     // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
 {

     // added different min loglevel for dev and staging
     if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.EnvironmentName.Equals("local", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     {
         loggerFactory.AddContext(LogLevel.Debug);
     }
     else if (env.IsStaging())
     {
         loggerFactory.AddContext(LogLevel.Information);
     }
     else // producton
     {
         loggerFactory.AddContext(LogLevel.Error);
     }

     loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
     {
         builder.AddConsole();
     });

     if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.EnvironmentName.Equals("local", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     {
         app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
     }

     app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();

     app.UseHttpsRedirection();

     app.UseCors(x => x
         .AllowAnyOrigin()
         .AllowAnyMethod()
         .AllowAnyHeader());

     app.UseStatusCodePages();

     app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
     {
         OnPrepareResponse = context =>
         {
             var headers = context.Context.Response.GetTypedHeaders();
             headers.CacheControl = new Microsoft.Net.Http.Headers.CacheControlHeaderValue()
             {
                 MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(30),
             };            
         }
     });

     app.UseAuthentication();
     app.UseRouting();
     app.UseAuthorization();     
     app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
     {
         endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
         endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
         //endpoints.MapRazorPages();
     });
 }


Can you please share a [mre]?

I have added the reproducible example. Please open up my question.

I would gladly reopen the question, but currently there is not enough information. Please provide the full exception text and the Startup class.

Provided the full exception text and the Startup class. Thankyou.

Your startup.cs has two constructors accepting 1 parameter which is a problem for DI as it doesn't know which one to use to build the service. You should remove one constructor

Removing the extra constructor worked for me.

I removed the extra constructor
 public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

And got rid of this error.
